# SyntaxHighlighter Library

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Does anyone know of a good Library that i can include in a project i am working on to highlight HTML, CSS, JS, etc code within either a TextBox/RTB control(s)?

I see alot of "How to Implement" but no one created a library that i can consume within an application.

I would be more than happy to make a DLL but need some good "Solid" information for how to implement source highlighting.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised to see an off-topic question from someone who's had his code reviewed here before... check out [ColorCode](http://colorcode.codeplex.com/) (though unfortunately, it doesn't look like it has RichTextBox support).

Comment: Its more of a clearner implementation, to see if someone has build a library or libraries for the various code-bases.  No sense in reinventing the wheel if someone has create one that is good enough ;)

Comment: @codesparkle sorry i flip between the two sites just wasnt paying much attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a good place to start. It is not the best implementation, but will get you going.
http://syntaxhighlighter.codeplex.com

Comment: problem with this code, is that its meant for the BlogEngine.Net library.  Working on severing product specific information and making it a generic library for code highlighting.  TYVM for the pointer